# Unable to get Cheat Toast to show and when pressing the back button the application is not going back to the previous screen

Tags: java, android

I am following some coding tutorials from The Big Nerd Ranch book for Android, 2nd edition.  I have followed all examples, but i cannot get the judgment_toast to show in my QuizActivity.java file.  Also when pressing back on the the application does not go back to the main question screen.

Please see all my code from all 3 classes below.....any help is much appreciated.

```
package uk.co.sbworrallgmail.geoquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT = 0;

    private boolean mIsCheater;

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mCheatButton;

    private ImageButton mNextButton;
    private ImageButton mPrevButton;

    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private Question[] mQuestionsBank = new Question[]{
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });
        mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionsBank.length;
                mIsCheater = false;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        mPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex -1) % mQuestionsBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        mCheatButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
        mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //  Start CheatActivity
                boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
                Intent intent = CheatActivity.newIntent(QuizActivity.this, answerIsTrue);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT);
            }
        });
        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionsBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        }
        updateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }
    @Override

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
    }

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

        int messageResId = 0;

        if (mIsCheater) {
            messageResId = R.string.judgment_toast;
        } else {
            if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
                messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
            } else {
                messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            mIsCheater = CheatActivity.wasAnswerShown(data);
        }
    }
}
```

and my CheatActivity.java file

```
package uk.co.sbworrallgmail.geoquiz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "uk.co.sbworrallgmail.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
    private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_SHOWN = "uk.co.sbworrallgmail.geoquiz.answer_is_shown";

    private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;

    private TextView mAnswerTextView;

    private Button mShowAnswer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

        mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

        mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_Text_View);

        mShowAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_Answer_Button);
        mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                } else {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                }
                setAnswerShownResult(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
        return intent;
    }

    private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    }

    public static boolean wasAnswerShown(Intent result) {
        return result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_SHOWN, false);
    }

}
```

and my Question.java file

```
package uk.co.sbworrallgmail.geoquiz;

public class Question {

    private int mTextResId;

    private boolean mAnswerTrue;

    public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
    }

    public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }

    public int getTextResId() {
        return mTextResId;
    }

    public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
        return mAnswerTrue;
    }

    public Question(int textResId, boolean answerTrue) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }
}
```

and my Manifest file as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.sbworrallgmail.geoquiz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".QuizActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CheatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cheat"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why down grade me to -1 just for placing Android Code in the title?

Comment: I did not downvote but maybe the reason is that someone thinks you posted either too much or too little code. When asking for help with code which is not working, one should provide an [MCVE]. In your case, I suspect you could leave out some elements and still reproduce the problematic behavior

Answer (score 1):

How is your activity set up for the back button? Show your manifest.

However...

Your toast is not working, more than likely, because the Toast takes a String value for the second param, you are giving it an int....

Try this instead.

```
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionsBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

        String messageResId = "";

        if (mIsCheater) {
            messageResId = getResources().getString(R.string.judgment_toast);
        } else {
            if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
                messageResId = getResources().getString(R.string.correct_toast);
            } else {
                messageResId = getResources().getString(R.string.incorrect_toast);
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I have added my Manifest file, thanks.

Also making the changes you have requested makes no difference.
I think it might be something to do with the Intent's?  But am not 100% sure, maybe something to do with the back button not working as well?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the back button not working as expected by making a change to the Manifest.xml file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".CheatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cheat"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
```

I changed the theme to match the theme of the parent application and now the back button works as expected.

Also the issue with the toasts is now working.  It was my expectation of what the application should be doing that was incorrect.